# IntegrityError when saving Django inherited model with custom ID field

Tags: django, django-models

I get an error when saving the model with custom primary key - `id` field.

My model:

```
class TestZ(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=7)
    field0 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class TestX(TestZ):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class TestA(TestX):
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class TestB(TestX):
    pass
```

Error:

```
>>> TestB.objects.create(pk='aa', field0='0', field1='1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 157, in create
    return self.get_queryset().create(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 322, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 545, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 573, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 654, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 687, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 232, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1514, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 903, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 451, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: myapp_testb.testx_ptr_id
```

Without custom `pk` field in `TestZ` I can save objects.
From admin page I can add an objects, there are no errors.

`Django==1.6.5`

Comment: What happens if you create the object using `id` instead of `pk`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference the custom id field when creating the model object. I tested this out and it works --> TestB.objects.create(**id**='aa', field0='0', field1='1')